# View using if/else statement displays the wrong page - SwiftUI

Tags: if-statement, swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI and want to display a view based on a boolean value but every time I run my app in the simulator, it always runs the `else` part and displays `ContentView` instead of `OnboardingView`.

Kindly guide what I am doing wrong in the code.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct FirstApp: App {
    
    @AppStorage("isOnboarding") var isOnboarding: Bool = true
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            
            if isOnboarding {
                OnboardingView()
            } else
            {
                ContentView()
            }
                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You likely have set `isOnboarding` to `false` at some point in UserDefaults (in this or another part of the app), so instead of using the default value (`true`), it's using what is stored in `UserDefaults` -- this is expected behavior. You could change the key to `"isOnboarding-2"` to test this -- an unused key should use the default value.

Comment: Agreed with jnpdx... the issue is not in the code you posted

Comment: @jnpdx i have another view for a button which is having the same IsOnboarding but that button is also not exiting the view. is there some wrong logic or what

'import SwiftUI

struct StartButtonView: View {
   // Mark: Properties
    
    @AppStorage("isOnboarding") var isOnboarding: Bool?
    
    // Mark : Body
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            isOnboarding = false
        }){
 '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works fine. The *"problem"* is the persisted value in your device for key `"isOnboarding"` is false (the default value that you have assigned will work only the first them). To make sure that this statement is right, you can do a simple test: toggle the `isOnboarding` value and relaunch the app. Something like this:

```
@main
struct FirstApp: App {
    @AppStorage("isOnboarding") var isOnboarding: Bool = true
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            Toggle(isOn: $isOnboarding) {
                Text("isOnboarding")
            }
            
            if isOnboarding {
                OnboardingView()
            } else {
                ContentView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a toggle on top and when i switch the toggle on it turns on the onboardingview but it is showing on every view of the app.

Comment: The toggle was just for demonstration, so you can see that after switching it on and relaunching the app, you will see the `OnboardingView`, and after switching it off and relaunching the app, you will see the `ContentView `. Remove the toggle once you test it.

Comment: If you want a variable that will not persist between app sessions use `@State` instead of `@AppStorage`